# Issue with Hyper-V, Virtual Ethernet and Physical NIC's

Tags: hyper-v-server-2016

I am trying to work out why this configuration is not working as expected. I am trying to get a number of VM's using one physical port and a number of other VM's using another physical port and at the moment, all traffic seems to be using just one physical port.

I have the following hardware on a server running Hyper-V (on Windows Server 2016):

- 4x 1Gb Physical NIC's on a server (identified as Broadcom, Broadcom #2, #3 and #4)
- Each physical NIC on the host has its own public IP address connected to its own separate port at the datacentre.

On Hyper-V I have configured two virtual ethernet adapters (Hyper-v Virtual Adapter and #2), each one configured to use a separate NIC.

On the VM's I have selected that they use one or the other vEthernet adapter.

My assumption is that the VM would use the selected vEthernet adapter and this would then use the physical NIC on the server for its outgoing traffic.

The reality is that all traffic seems to be using just one NIC, regardless of which vEthernet is selected in the Settings of the VM.

Have I misunderstood how this works or am I doing something wrong?

(In the images NIC3 is just an internal network).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the two network adapters have any IP configuration on the host adapter?

Comment: @GregAskew Yes, (I will update) each physical NIC has its own public IP address on the host server.

Comment: How did you determine that all of the virtual machines are using a single physical adapter?

Comment: @joeqwerty In two ways... 1) The VM's use high bandwidth and one of the ports is reaching its capacity and 2) the traffic through the ports is being monitored on the switch they are connected to and one is showing all the traffic and the other port is showing next to nothing, so I'm quite confident all the traffic is going only over one of the two NIC's.

Comment: Neither of those pieces of evidence is confirmation of what you suspect. If it were me, I'd disconnect the physical NIC that you think all the traffic is going through and see if any of the virtual machines can communicate.